# HTML formatted Plot title text in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to format a figure's title text to display a tooltip on hover using bootstrap in bokeh. I know that you can add Div widget (http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#div) but I was wondering if there was an easy to format text, specifically the title, using html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the `Title` annotation is rendered on the HTML Canvas, which has very limited text rendering capability, as compared to usual HTML/CSS styling options. If you need something apart from simple font size and style then using a div above the plot for a title is the best bet.